# Automatic backup from s3 to another server or cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am using [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org) to backup my files from s3, I run the following command from my terminal to sync between my files in my_bucket and my **local** folder called workfiles which is in the home directory

```
s3cmd sync s3://my_bucket/ /home/mody/workfiles/ --delete-removed
```

This is a manual method and it will be painful if the volume is big, so I am wondering if it's possible to do some kind of automatic backup to a server like digitalocean or some other cloud service, and how to do that ? any code snippet will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What about setting it up as a cron job?

Comment: @Uzbekjon yeah but I don't want to backup files to my local disk! I am asking how to do backups to another web server or another cloud storage

Comment: Just setup a cron job on that server and you're done. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: @medBo as part of your question you asked if it was possible to "backup to a server like digitalocean" and setting up a cron job on a digitalocean server to pull from S3 would be the way you would accomplish that. Not sure why you took the suggestion of using a "cron job" as an answer that only applies to "local disk".

Comment: @Uzbekjon oh sorry I don't have any idea as this is the first time I am going to do a such thing, I heard before about cron job but I've never used it :) so from what I understand it will be like I am using a local computer!

Comment: @MarkB I thought it would be different that doing that in local !! I have no previous experience with these stuffs really!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our discussion, you may setup a cronjob to schedule tasks on your local/remote server. Different linux distributions might have different crontab files setup for you. For example, according to [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-schedule-routine-tasks-with-cron-and-anacron-on-a-vps), DigitalOcean has hourly, daily, etc. crontab folders setup for your convenience for their Ubuntu instances.

So, you can create a file with your command to execute in `/etc/cron.daily` folder:

```
s3cmd sync s3://my_bucket/ /path/to/backupfolder/ --delete-removed
```

Make sure to install s3tools on your remote machine as well.

Comment: Thank you I got it. I will also be able to setup an http server so if s3 goes down I will just replace the path to my images by my digital ocean url, for example if image url is `s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/image1.png` then it will be `http://myserver.com/images/image1.png` in urgency case, right ?

Comment: Yeap, but don't forget to install and setup a webserver on that machine as well (nginx would be a good choice for your case).

Answer (score 10):

Cherry Software have cloud solution to run storage backup that might be of use to you .  This is Azure to S3 and back I believe.

https://www.cherrysafe.com/Home/Features#storageBackup

Not tried it myself but it is spin off company from redgate so has good background pedigree.

Comment: Actually as the original developer of Cherry Safe in Redgate and now it's owner I can confirm that it can do S3 to Azure blob backups too. There are a few restrictions around how metadata is translated as Azure metadata is more restrictive than S3.